# If $f$ be non-negative, bounded and Riemann Integrable on $[a, b]$, then $\sqrt{f}$ is R- integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, alternative-proof, riemann-integration

The easiest way to solve this is to use the theorem: If $g$ be a continuous function in $[M, m] \subset [j, k]$ and $f$ be bounded and Riemann integrable, then $g \circ f$ is Riemann integrable too. Using $g(x) = x^{1/2}$ solves the problem, but I want to prove it more directly.

Here is my approach:

From the necessary and sufficient condition of integrability, we have

$\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists$ a $\delta >0$ such that, $0 \leq W(P,f) = \sum_{r=1}^{n} (M_r-m_r)\delta_r=U(P,f)-L(P,f) < \epsilon $ $\  \forall \  ||P||< \delta$, $P$ being any partition of $[a,b]$.

We now create a set ( more precisely, a subset of the index set $I$ ), $Z$, defined as $Z=\{r \in I: \sup_{[x_{r-1},x_r]}f=\sup_{[x_{r-1},x_r]}\sqrt{f}=0\}$. Since the function is non negative over the entire interval, therefore, in every interval indexed in $Z$ must have $0$ as the infimum.

By the property of non negative real numbers, $m_r \leq f \leq M_r \implies \sqrt{m_r} \leq \sqrt{f} \leq \sqrt{M_r}$

Now taking $W(P^*,\sqrt{f})= \sum_{r\in I\Z}(\sqrt{M_r}-\sqrt{m_r})\delta_r =\sum_{r\in I\Z}\frac{({M_r}-{m_r})}{(\sqrt{M_r}+\sqrt{m_r})}\delta_r \leq \mu\sum_{r\in I\Z}({M_r}-{m_r})\delta_r $

choosing $\min \{\sqrt{M_r}+\sqrt{m_r}: r \in I\Z\}= K = 1/\mu >0 (\neq0$, by our choice of $r$) .

We further have $\sqrt{M_r}-\sqrt{m_r} = 0 =M_r -m_r \ \forall r\in Z.$ Hence $W(P^*,\sqrt{f})= W(P,\sqrt{f}) $

Now, $\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists$ a $\delta_\mu >0$ such that, $0 \leq W(P,f) = \sum_{r=1}^{n} (M_r-m_r)\delta_r< \epsilon/\mu $ [$\mu$ is a fixed positive real number] $\  \forall \  ||P||< \delta_\mu$, $P$ being any partition of $[a,b]$.

Thus, we finally have the following:
$\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists$ a $\delta_\mu >0$ such that, $0 \leq W(P,\sqrt{f}) \leq \mu \ W(P,f) < \epsilon $, $\forall \  ||P||< \delta_\mu.$

P.S : I am aware of the duplicates. I just want my solution verified.

Comment: It would have been pretty neat and clean if $f$ were $>0$. The problem arises when $0$ is in the range of $f$. This is when for some $i$,  $\epsilon / (\sqrt{M_i}+\sqrt{m_i})$ might become $\infty$. I just have modified the partition index to remove the trouble. Otherwise, it's just the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following your notation, note that we have 
$$\sqrt{M_i} - \sqrt{m_i} \leq \sqrt {M_i-m_i}$$
since $\sqrt{(M_i-m_i) + m_i}  \leq \sqrt {M_i-m_i} + \sqrt{m_i}$.

To bound the Riemann sum,
$$\sum_i (\sqrt{M_i} - \sqrt{m_i}) \delta_i \leq \sum_i \sqrt {(M_i-m_i)\delta_i} \sqrt \delta_i \leq \left( \sum_i  (M_i-m_i)\delta_i\right)^{1/2} \left( \sum_i \delta_i\right)^{1/2} $$
because $f$ is Riemann integrable, $\sum_i  (M_i-m_i)\delta_i$ can be made arbritrily small, and  $\sum_i \delta_i =  b-a$ is bounded, we are done.

Comment: Good one. But is mine alright?

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas In your argument, does $\mu$ (or the index set $Z$ and $I$)  depend on the partition?

Comment: Everything you mentioned changes according to the mode of Partition. But  ultimately, we can show that it can be made less than any predetermined positive quantity.

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas In the second last line, you mentioned [$\mu$ is a fixed constant], how did you pick this fixed constant? Also it would be hard to estimate "$\mu \sum_{i\in I\setminus Z} (M_i - m_i) \delta i$". Take $f(x) = x$ on $(0,1]$ and $f(0) = 1$, in this case $Z$ is empty. The quantity $\mu \sum_{i\in I} (M_i - m_i) \delta_i$ is hard to control as the partition size goes to zero, since $\mu$ goes to infinity and $\sum_{i\in I} (M_i - m_i) \delta i$ goes to zero.

Comment: unfortunately, I have to agree.

Comment: in defence of my argument (kind of): We have the freedom to choose any epsilon. $\mu$ is never really infinite, but it has no upper bound. That's true. But we get the effect of unboundedness nullified by multiplying $\mu$ with $\epsilon / \mu$, in the last stage of the proof. In case of your example, it is indeed hard to control the jumps of $\mu$, but I think the argument holds up was somehow.